# What should I use in this case: "despite", "though," or "even though"?

Tags: word-choice, formality

> That way my mom can move on, find someone else, **despite** having sworn
>   she'd only marry God."
>
> That way my mom can move on, find someone else, **though** she swore
>   she'd only marry God."
>
> That way my mom can move on, find someone else, **even though** she swore
>   she'd only marry God."

Which is the correct option? Or at least the one that sounds most natural/less formal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first one is correct.

You have to phrase the others like this:

> That way my mom can move on, find someone else, (even) though ***she swore*** she'd only marry God."

EDIT: If you're trying to decide which one sounds the least formal, I'd say go with the third one.

Comment: Oh, yeah that's how I wrote it initially. I updated it in the aswer.

Comment: @janoChen: *Despite* sounds a bit more formal. I'd pick the 3rd one to sound natural.

Comment: I see, the second one sounds weird?

Comment: @janoChen: Little bit, yeah.

Answer (score 1):

If by *correct* you mean *grammatical*, then all three sentences are grammatical, although some might argue for inserting an *and* after *move on,*.

As for formality, my intuitive response on reading the sentences was that the *despite* variant is the most formal. This may be because the *despite having + past participle* seems less common than the *(even) though + subject + past tense* variant - as these two Ngrams show: [sworn](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=despite%20having%20sworn%2Ceven%20though%20she%20swore&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdespite%20having%20sworn%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ceven%20though%20she%20swore%3B%2Cc0) - [said](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=despite%20having%20said%2C%20even%20though%20she%20said&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdespite%20having%20said%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ceven%20though%20she%20said%3B%2Cc0).

In terms of semantics, both the *despite* variant and the *even though* variant suggest to me a stronger contrast between what she swore and what she should now do.